# Why Google analytics firebase never shows parameters of custom event?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using react-native-firebase analytics for tracking user events in google analytics, I can see the event name in the console of google analytics, but without the parameter item and its value.

I waited also 24 hours without any change.

```
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
....
analytics().logEvent('basket', { item: 'mens grey t-shirt', });
```

[[Screenshot:]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2NO8.png)

[Screenshot parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmlHe.png)

[Screenshot event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0AAz.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics reporting. More details here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209

In the current version of Firebase console the "Edit parameter reporting" action is gone. Custom parameters are now added through "Manage Custom Definitions" menu on top of the event list.

[image]

Comment: Ok i made a custom dimension parameter called item, the same as in logevent, do I need to wait until tomorrow to see it?

Comment: Yes, you will see them at least from tomorrow.

Comment: I can see the parameter value only but without its name, like mens grey t-shirt but without the name of parameter item

Comment: What do you mean? Attach a screenshot, pls

Comment: I add two Screenshots, I can not see the item in Screenshot parameter.

Comment: It means that there aren't event selected in last 30 minutes.

Comment: The linked page to the documentation seems to be blank now, fun times. SInce GA4 is all the rage now it seems like we're in a limbo period where React Native Firebase Analytics and custom dimensions aren't compatible with each other. I would like to see this data:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9268042?hl=en&ref_topic=10331681